# Any good example or advice about using AES encryption in J2ME?

Tags: encryption, java-me, aes

I'm connecting mi cell phone application in J2ME to a web service and I have to send a SHA256 hash to it in order to validate some data received. I also need to be capable to store some information encrypted into the cell phone. I was thinking to use AES (rinjdael) symmetric encryption.

Anyone knows about any code example using AES encryption in J2ME ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise looking into the open source bouncycastle library.

It has been successfully used for cryptography on J2ME.

Comment: Definitevely I'd been searching other libraries too, but after a week to check, the only one reasonably complete is Bouncy Castle.